# SQL fetch rows with column value equal to max value

Tags: sql, postgresql, max

I got the following table with the query `select count(category), name  from product natural join supplier group by name;`:

```
 count |   nome    
-------+-----------
     1 | CandyCorp
     1 | Nike
     1 | DrinksInc
     7 | Mutante
     1 | Colt
     7 | Mazzetti
```

Now I want to fetch only the rows with count equal to the max value on the count column (in this case 7), getting:

```
 count |   nome    
-------+-----------
     7 | Mutant
     7 | Mazzetti
```

EDIT: I got it working by creating a temporary table:

```
create table auxtable as (select count(categoria),name from product natural join supplier group by name);

select name from auxtable a1 join (select max(count) as countMax from auxtable) a2 on a1.count=a2.countMax;

drop table auxtable;
```

Is there a way to this in a single query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use CTE instead of temp table:

```
with auxtable as (select count(categoria),name from product natural join supplier group by name)
select name from auxtable a1 
join (select max(count) as countMax from auxtable) a2 on a1.count=a2.countMax;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rank() over (order by count(*) desc)` to rank by count and then just keep the #1 ranked items:

```
select * from (
    select
      rank() over (order by count(category) desc) rn, 
      name, count(category)
    from product natural join supplier
    group by name
) t where rn = 1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/26b68/1

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, since this is an assignment, I'm not allowed to use rank().